# Why do I have so many Traces entries in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to clean up App Insights logs. I noticed in the Traces table, I get thousands of the same 2 messages. I was wondering if anyone knew where they came from, and can they be prevented from being added further? They don't seem to provide any value to my team, and if they just take up a ton of unnecessary space, I'd like them removed, at least moving forward. The messages in particular are:

Message="Goal state with incarnation 1 retrieved."

and

Message="Retrieving goal state from fabric..."

These literally get added multiple times, every minute. I have not found any evidence of these strings in our code, nor have I found any information about this on the web. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about and how is it hosted, azure web app?

Comment: It is a multiple project web application and connector to SharePoint Online. It's hosted on a cloud server of ours. Forgive my ignorance of anything else, but I'm pretty green to Azure and cloud programming